# gRPC - Reply with Array

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, grpc-c#

I'm trying to figure out how to properly pass an array in a server response in gRPC.

In proto (after reading the google documentation) i did:

```
message HelloReply {
  repeated string message = 1;
}
```

in service method:

```
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
   return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
   {
      Message = //myArray in foreach with replys = myArray.Length? 
   });
}
```

What i must to do here? Stream? But what should it look like?

I easily implemented this in the WCF, but with gRPS I ran into a wall. I have not found a basic implementation of such tasks anywhere, except for passing one string (by default in the c# template).

p.s. maybe there is some book with implementation examples in c# or something like that (except for the official documentation)?

Comment: Make response CSV with commas separating values.

Comment: where is an array ? You passed a class with a string. There is no array (and please don't answer, that a string is just a array of chars)

Comment: Do you see an array? Not? And he is. Out of context! :)) p.s. myArray <--

Comment: :)---------------------:)

Comment: please read some tutorials before asking questions in stackoverflow

Comment: a string is not a array in grpc. It's a text to send to the client. It will send in the end of the server function. If you like to send charater by charater you need to change the response to IAsyncEnumerable<Char>, then you can put chars to the client when ever you want.
But there are great tutorials teaching this, take this time to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have my dev machine on me right now, but this is roughly what you do to populate a repeated protobuf field.  I believe this is what you were after based on the comments in your code.

```
HelloReply reply = new HelloReply();
foreach(var rep in myArray)
{
   reply.Message.Add(rep);
}
return Task.FromResult(reply);
```

If this is not what you are after let me know.

Comment: This is not quite the same and it doesn’t work in the stream (it doesn’t work for me), but this is the solution that also seemed to me to be correct. Thanks for the reply though, it's motivating. I found a database of examples on github, maybe it will help others - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples

Comment: @UNRE  Could you post your grpc service?  I guess I did not get that your call was a server side stream.  It looks to me that the response is a message with a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you want to pass the array into gRPC Response, you can probably serialize it into JSON String and pass it as a string to the response and decode it at the destination.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).